# I can't find an adequate conditional model for this time series

Tags: time-series, arima, garch, acf-pacf, volatility

I have the European TTF GAS spot Price time series from 31/12/1990 to 31/10/2022:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Iu84-oFtv3-ybmp72IJ_s1DfcTG_TDu7/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=117791817408001078818&rtpof=true&sd=true

I downloaded it from Word Bank:

https://www.worldbank.org/en/research/commodity-markets

I would like to model TTS price or return dynamics by a conditional model for the mean and a conditional model for the variance. I found many papers that fit an ARMA(1,1)-GARCH(1,1) to the raw returns, I tried with multiple ARMA(p,q)-GARCH(r,s)-types models with both a Student-t and a Gaussian distributional assumption for the innovations (of course also comparing models according to BIC and AIC), but every times standardized residuals and/or their squared values present some high degree of autocorrelation. For example ARMA(1,0)-GARCH(1,1) assuming Student-t distribution for the innovations gives:
[image: Autocorrelation of Standardized Residuals]

In the figure the second row are standardized residuals and the third are squared standardized residuals.
Then I assumed that autocorrelation may be imputable to the seasonal nature of Natural GAS, therefore I deseasonalized log(P) without the dummy-variables approach, but nothing changed. How can Natural GAS TTF spot price be modeled?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some thoughts:

- Statistically significant (partial) autocorrelations at high-order lags that are not associated with seasonal frequencies (12, 24, 36, ...) may be due to chance.
- Structural breaks may induce persistence and autocorrelations at high-order lags and otherwise mess a lot up. Instead of modelling untransformed series with ARMA-GARCH, modelling log-returns or other transformations that involve differencing may alleviate the problem.* (David Hendry, Jennifer Castle and "robust forecasting devices" are some relevant names and keywords; an example of a relevant paper is Castle et al. ["Robust Approaches to Forecasting"](https://ideas.repec.org/p/oxf/wpaper/697.html) (2014).) But it seems you are already doing that, so it has not worked as well as one might have hoped.
- Indeed, if you plot the data you will notice that at least the last 18 months show quite different behaviour than the preceding 30 years. I doubt the same model that would fit the 1991-2020 period nicely would fit the 2021-2022 data reasonably well. Out of curiosity, would ARMA(1,1)-GARCH(1,1) with some seasonal adjustment work OK for 1991-2020?
- 30+ years is a while. In addition to potential structural breaks, there may be some gradual changes in the data generating process. Using the same time-constant model for the entire sample might therefore produce some undesirable artefacts.
- You diagnostic QQ plot shows violations of normality. However, that need not be a problem, as you said your model assumes a Student-$t$ distribution. Try using the appropriate QQ plot instead.
- What is the difference between the second and third rows of plots? Are raw standardized residuals used in the second row while squared ones in the third row?

*This may come at a cost. Generally, differencing a time series that is not integrated leads to overdifferencing and its problems (e.g. a unit root moving-average component is introduced).

Comment: Yes I found the structural break: in the variable description they say that 'Natural Gas (Europe), from April 2015, Netherlands Title Transfer Facility (TTF); April 2010 to March 2015, average import border price and a spot price component, including UK; during June 2000 - March 2010 prices excludes UK. ' I think this is the reason why things keeps messing up. If I consider the Apr/2010-Dec/2019 then the AR(1)-GARCH(1,1) seems quite more reasonable. Is there any (easy) way to incorporate in the model information preceding Apr/2010? Thank you

Comment: @Barbab, if you have reason to believe some statistical characteristics of the time series have remained the same across the periods, you can have a single model with some dummy variables for the ones that changed. E.g. a dummy in the conditional mean equation for a level shift in the cond. mean or a dummy in the cond. variance equation for a shift in the level of cond. variance. Otherwise, you can just fit separate models.